# Prove that between every 2 vertex exists path with at least $\frac{1}{2}$ probability.

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Let we have $n$ vertexes and for every 2 vertex we have an edge between them with $\frac{1}{2}$ probability.

The question is to prove that this graph is connected (exist a path between every 2 vertexes) with at least $\frac{1}{2}$ probability.

Here's what I think about this problem:

Seems like we want to find probability that graph is non-connected (And it has to be less than $\frac{1}{2}$). But how we want to find this?

Perhaps we should say the right words that we will have, on average, half of the edges in this graph and somehow estimate the probability that a graph is connected with so many edges.

Comment: The usual proof is to show that if $G$ is disconnected then its complement graph is connected.

Comment: Is it enough to say that we can pair our graphs into pairs and note that at least one of them connected? Seems like no cuz we don't know anything about probability of such graphs?

Comment: All of the graphs have the same probability in this model